# How to publish multiple projects in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a question. I created a web application using ASP.NET Core 3.1 in Visual Studio 2022. In the solution, I have three projects, the first is my main project, the second is the admin panel and the third is the repository where I created the models and connected to the database, as well as here all migrations are located.

The question is how to publish these projects on a server or hosting. For example, on smarterаsp. Screenshot of the projects is attached here:

[image]

Also I need to load the database.

Please provide a detailed instruction if possible.

Comment: 3 projects used api to call and be called? and where you want to publish to? Your IIS? Azure app service? or something else?

Comment: No, the are working by mapping, and i want to add my project to smarterasp